# creating a new table, from various tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a select query using joins but know I want to create a table from it. But sql keeps saying I have an error next to the '(', but all the examples I have seen have a similar syntax

```
create table [dbo].[PoliceDataNor] as
(
select
    pc.[CrimeID],
    ct.[CrimeTypeID],
    m.[MonthID],
    fw.FallsWithinID,
    ln.[LSOANameID],
    lc.[LSOACodeID]
from [dbo].[PoliceCrime] as pc, [dbo].[CrimeTypes] as ct, [dbo].[FallsWithins] as fw,
[dbo].[LSAOCodes] as lc, [dbo].[LSAONames] as ln, [dbo].[Months] as m
where
pc.[Crime type]= ct.[Crime type]
and
pc.[Falls within]= fw.[Falls within]
and 
pc.[LSOA code] = lc.[LSOA code]
and
pc.[LSOA name] = ln.[LSOA name]
and
pc.[Month] = m.[Month]
)
```

Comment: there is no `create table as select ..` in sql server. You should use `insert into tablename (col1,col2 ..) select ...`

Comment: Have you tried by removing select query out of brackets.

Comment: You really need to stop using this antiquated style of join. The ANSI-92 style join has been around now for close to 30 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done like so using modern joins.   Be aware that insert into doesn't copy indexes.  If you need to query you may want to consider adding them.

```
select
    pc.[CrimeID],
    ct.[CrimeTypeID],
    m.[MonthID],
    fw.FallsWithinID,
    ln.[LSOANameID],
    lc.[LSOACodeID]
into [dbo].[PoliceDataNor]
from [dbo].[PoliceCrime] as pc
join [dbo].[CrimeTypes] as ct
   on pc.[Crime type]= ct.[Crime type]
join [dbo].[FallsWithins] as fw
   on pc.[Falls within]= fw.[Falls within]
join [dbo].[LSAOCodes] as lc
   on pc.[LSOA code] = lc.[LSOA code]
join [dbo].[LSAONames] as ln
   pc.[LSOA name] = ln.[LSOA name]
join [dbo].[Months] as m
   pc.[Month] = m.[Month]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to select into:

```
select
    pc.[CrimeID],
    ct.[CrimeTypeID],
    m.[MonthID],
    fw.FallsWithinID,
    ln.[LSOANameID],
    lc.[LSOACodeID]
into [dbo].[PoliceDataNor]
from [dbo].[PoliceCrime] as pc, [dbo].[CrimeTypes] as ct, [dbo].[FallsWithins] as fw,
[dbo].[LSAOCodes] as lc, [dbo].[LSAONames] as ln, [dbo].[Months] as m
where
pc.[Crime type]= ct.[Crime type]
and
pc.[Falls within]= fw.[Falls within]
and 
pc.[LSOA code] = lc.[LSOA code]
and
pc.[LSOA name] = ln.[LSOA name]
and
pc.[Month] = m.[Month]
```